# How to prove that $\ln (N+1) - \ln (N) \geq \frac{1}{N+1}$

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality, induction, logarithms

How to prove that for each natural number ($N$) the following is true:

> $$\ln(N+1)-\ln(N) \geq \frac{1}{N+1}$$

I tried using induction but it seems like the end of a road.
The first case on ($N=0$) was easy but the rest not.

**Note: I'm looking for solution using induction**

Comment: This follows from $\ln(1+x)\le x$ for all $x>-1$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng:  that was my first thought, but wouldn't that just show $\ln(N+1)-\ln(N)=\ln(1+1/N)<1/N$ not $\ge\dfrac1{N+1}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Take $x=-1/(N+1)$, not $x=1/N$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng:  that works; thanks

Answer (score 5):

The area under the curve $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$ between $x=N$ and $x=N+1$ is greater than the area of a rectangle of width $1$ and height $\dfrac{1}{N+1}$.

Draw a sketch to see this.

Comment: I am looking for formal prove not using graph

Comment: Plus, you should look at the integral of ln(x) not the directive, that's how we calculate area

Comment: I didn't check it @clark_smith I am just saying that you can use integral for formal prove.

Comment: @clark Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: I wrote it yes it's right, could someone please add a solution using Induction, I'm interested in that way and want to know how we can solve it

Comment: @clark_smith Consider $f(x):=\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)-\frac{1}{x+1}$. Show $f$ is strictly decreasing (calculate $f'$) and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$. It follows that $f(x)>0$. This can also be done in terms of sequences (perhaps that is what you want).

Answer (score 1):

$\ln (N+1) - \ln (N) =$

$\ln {\frac {N+1}N} = $

$\int_1^{\frac {N+1}N} \frac 1t dt$

Now $\frac {N+1}N> 1$ and  for $1\le x \le \frac {N+1}N$ we have $1 \ge \frac 1x \ge \frac N{N+1}$

So $[\frac {N+1}N - 1]\cdot 1 \ge \int_1^{\frac {N+1}N} \frac 1t dt \ge [\frac {N+1}N - 1]\cdot \frac N{N+1}$

So $\frac 1N \ge \ln(N+1)-\ln N \ge \frac 1N\cdot \frac N{N+1}=\frac 1{N+1}$

Comment: Why not $\ln(N+1)-\ln(N)=\int_N^{N+1}{dt\over t}\ge\int_N^{N+1}{dt\over N+1}={1\over N+1}$?

Comment: No reason.  If I'm going back to basics, then I'm going to *really* go back to basics.

Answer (score 0):

This way is a bit long-winded but it does work. **Note**: I started writing this before the request for a proof by induction was made.

Consider $$\ln(N+1)-\ln(N)$$

$$=\ln\bigg(\frac{N+1}{N}\bigg)$$

$$=\ln\bigg(1 +\frac{1}{N}\bigg)$$

$$=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j+1}\Big(\frac{1}{N}\Big)^j}{j}$$

The Taylor series converges if $|\frac{1}{N}|< 1$, so this works for $N\ge 2$. However, the cases for $N = 0,1$ are easy to verify by calculation.

For $N \ge 2$,

$$\ln\bigg(1 +\frac{1}{N}\bigg) = \frac{1}{(1)N} - \frac{1}{(2)N^2} + \frac{1}{(3)N^3} -\frac{1}{(4)N^4} + \cdots$$

$$= \Bigg(\frac{1}{(1)N} - \frac{1}{(2)N^2}\Bigg) + \Bigg(\frac{1}{(3)N^3} -\frac{1}{(4)N^4}\Bigg) + \cdots$$

It should be clear that each bracketed term is positive; thus,

$$\ln\bigg(1 +\frac{1}{N}\bigg) > \frac{1}{N} - \frac{1}{2N^2}$$

Now consider

$$\Bigg(\frac{1}{N} - \frac{1}{2N^2}\Bigg) - \Bigg(\frac{1}{N+1}\Bigg)$$

$$ = \Bigg(\frac{2N-1}{2N^2}\Bigg) - \Bigg(\frac{1}{N+1}\Bigg)$$

$$ = \frac{N-1}{(2N^2)(N+1)} $$

$$ > 0 $$ since  $N \ge 2$. Therefore,

$$\frac{1}{N} - \frac{1}{2N^2} > \frac{1}{N+1} $$

$$\implies \ln\bigg(1 +\frac{1}{N}\bigg) \ge \frac{1}{N+1}$$